# Encrypting the face region in OpenCV

Tags: java, opencv

Following is the code to detect a face in OpenCV and draws a rectangle around the ace region.

```
class FaceDetect {
      public void run() {

        CascadeClassifier faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier("C:\\Users\\powerohit\\workspace\\OpenCV\\lbpcascade_frontalface.xml");

        Mat image = Imgcodecs.imread("C:\\Users\\powerohit\\workspace\\OpenCV\\rohit.jpg");
        MatOfRect faceDetections = new MatOfRect();
        faceDetector.detectMultiScale(image, faceDetections);
        System.out.println(String.format("Detected %s faces", faceDetections.toArray().length));
        for (Rect rect : faceDetections.toArray()) {
            Imgproc.rectangle(image, new Point(rect.x, rect.y), new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height), new Scalar(0, 255, 0));


        }


        String filename = "faceDetection1.png";
        System.out.println(String.format("Writing %s", filename));
        Imgcodecs.imwrite(filename, image);
      }
    }
    public class HelloOpenCV {
      public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
        new FaceDetect().run();
      }
    }
```

Now I have to encrypt the face region in the rectangle. I have developed a code to encrypt the data, but I need to extract the face region into an array and then encrypt it and place it back to the face region.

How to get the face region of the image??

Comment: what do you mean with encrypting? you mean anonymizing? if it is that you can try resizing that region to a small image and then resize it up... this will pixelize such a region, also you can blur it or replace it with random pixels.

Comment: I need to copy that part of the region into a one dimensional array ..I'll perform encryption on that array and recopy that part into the image...

Comment: This is from the docs. I did not try: `Mat subMat = image.submat(rect.x, rect.y, rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height);` . Should get you a Mat with the data.